# Xcode "ld: library not found" for C++ makefile project

Tags: c++, xcode

OS: Mac 10.14.6 -- Xcode ver: 11.3.1

I have an external C++ project (that uses an existing makefile to build) that I imported into Xcode, and when I try to build it I get the following error message: `ld: library not found for -ljpeg`.

Strangely, when I run the same build command (`$make all-recursive`) from the command line, it builds successfully. I've double-checked and the relevant .dylib files DO exist in /usr/local/lib. From reading around the web it seemed like Xcode build-settings needed library search paths to include the directory where the .dylib files are, so I added LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS under target "Build Settings", but that did not solve the problem.

Is there any reason that comes to mind why Xcode's build command would fail but mine wouldn't?

[image: Error Message]

[image: Build Settings]

Comment: Drag the .dylib into your xcode project

Comment: Once I've done that, how do I tell Xcode 11 to link those libraries? I would have /thought/ that it would be the "Link Binaries with Libraries" phase, but it is greyed out.

Comment: Are you copying the files to the destination folder when you drag them into xcode? XCode pops up with a prompt asking you to do so.

Comment: When dragging the dylibs into the root project folder, I get a popup giving me three options: Destination: Copy Items If Needed (Unchecked), Added Folders (Create Groups), and Add To Targets (my project is selected). I physically copy-pasted the dylibs into the root project folder via Finder beforehand as well. I'm new to using Xcode, so if this dylib inclusion method is documented somewhere I'd be very grateful for a link! Unfortunately, the build still fails with the same error.

Comment: Try manually removing them from your root project folder, then dragging them in and checking the boxes "Copy Items If Needed" and "Add To Target" then compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link should also receive a flag of the form `-L<path>` which has the path to the jpeg library's parent folder, before the `-ljpeg` flag.

So add `-L/usr/local/lib` to the other linker flags build setting and try again.

Easy way to find the correct flags is running `pkg-config`:

```
pkg-config --libs libjpeg
-L/usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/9d/lib -ljpeg
```

If that fails, you can:

- Find the default paths the executable will look for the dylibs in: `otool -L executable`
- Copy the dylib from its original location.
- Paste it in a folder like `@executable_path/../Resources/lib` or `@loader_path/` or whatever the first step shows. Create those folders if needed.

Then rebuild.

Most robust way is to pass the full path in `-l` option, and not break it in two components.